Default background color of layout files is black
Whenever I create a new layout file in my android studio project, it's default background color is always black and I have to use     android:background="#FFF" to change it's color to white. But this creates a lot of challenges while designing.
Does anyone have a fix?
Here is the code of the xml file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.management.EnrollDevice.Fragments.FragmentFour"

    >




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Image of the Layout File

hi can u share an image of your layout file along with your code?

You are viewing your layout in night mode. In real device it will show white default. to view in day mode you have an option beside your emulater name with an moon icon. change it from there.

Check if System UI Mode is set to Not Night.
Also, the background color is likely to be black when the device running the app is set to dark mode. If you don't want to support dark mode, you may want to specify the base theme as Light instead of DayNight.

